# Summary data tables from wide data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, summary

I am trying to find lazy/easy ways of creating summary tables/`data.frames` from wide `data.frames`. Assume a following data.frame, but with many more columns so that specifying the column names takes a long time:

```
set.seed(2)
x <- data.frame(Rep = rep(1:3, 4), Temp = c(rep(10,6), rep(20,6)), 
pH = rep(c(rep(8.1, 3), rep(7.6, 3)), 2),
Var1 = rnorm(12, 5,2), Var2 = c(rnorm(6,4,1), rnorm(6,3,5)),
Var3 = rt(12, 20))
x[1:3] <- as.data.frame(apply(x[1:3], 2, function(x) as.factor(x)))
```

Now I can calculate summary statistics with `plyr`:

```
(mu <- ddply(x, .(Temp, pH), numcolwise(mean)))
(std <- ddply(x, .(Temp, pH), numcolwise(sd)))
(n  <- ddply(x, .(Temp, pH), numcolwise(length)))
```

But I am not able to figure out how to apply all of these functions at the same time:

```
ddply(x, .(Temp, pH), numcolwise(mean, sd, length))
```

I could of course merge various summary data.tables, but this would not be a "lazy / easy" way of doing this. I am looking for something general that I could apply in many instances. Something like this with the exception that it should be possible to generate with a single function:

```
xx <- merge(mu, std, by = c("Temp", "pH"), sotr = F)
colnames(xx) <- gsub("x", "mean", colnames(xx))
colnames(xx) <- gsub("y", "sd", colnames(xx))
xx <- merge(xx, n, by = c("Temp", "pH"), sotr = F)
colnames(xx)[(ncol(xx)-2):ncol(xx)] <-
paste0(colnames(xx)[(ncol(xx)-2):ncol(xx)], ".length")
xx <- xx[c("Temp", "pH", grep("Var1", colnames(xx), value = T),
grep("Var2", colnames(xx), value = T),
grep("Var3", colnames(xx), value = T))]
xx

  Temp  pH Var1.mean  Var1.sd Var1.length Var2.mean  Var2.sd Var2.length Var3.mean  Var3.sd Var3.length
1   10 7.6  4.281195 1.352194           3  3.534447 1.652884           3 0.1529616 1.076276           3
2   10 8.1  5.583853 2.491672           3  4.116622 1.478286           3 1.1611944 1.081301           3
3   20 7.6  5.840411 1.120549           3  6.907273 8.628021           3 0.1301949 1.764201           3
4   20 8.1  6.635154 2.232262           3  8.893188 4.208087           3 0.5509202 1.187431           3
```

Is this possible to do in **R** currently? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R's `aggregate` can actually handle this, but in a strange way:

```
(temp <- aggregate(. ~ Temp + pH, x, function(y) cbind(mean(y), sd(y), length(y))))
#   Temp  pH Rep.1 Rep.2 Rep.3   Var1.1   Var1.2   Var1.3   Var2.1   Var2.2   Var2.3
# 1   10 7.6     2     1     3 4.281195 1.352194 3.000000 3.534447 1.652884 3.000000
# 2   20 7.6     2     1     3 5.840411 1.120549 3.000000 6.907273 8.628021 3.000000
# 3   10 8.1     2     1     3 5.583853 2.491672 3.000000 4.116622 1.478286 3.000000
# 4   20 8.1     2     1     3 6.635154 2.232262 3.000000 8.893188 4.208087 3.000000
#      Var3.1    Var3.2    Var3.3
# 1 0.1529616 1.0762763 3.0000000
# 2 0.1301949 1.7642008 3.0000000
# 3 1.1611944 1.0813007 3.0000000
# 4 0.5509202 1.1874306 3.0000000
str(temp)
# 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ Temp: Factor w/ 2 levels "10","20": 1 2 1 2
#  $ pH  : Factor w/ 2 levels "7.6","8.1": 1 1 2 2
#  $ Rep : num [1:4, 1:3] 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 ...
#  $ Var1: num [1:4, 1:3] 4.28 5.84 5.58 6.64 1.35 ...
#  $ Var2: num [1:4, 1:3] 3.53 6.91 4.12 8.89 1.65 ...
#  $ Var3: num [1:4, 1:3] 0.153 0.13 1.161 0.551 1.076 ...
```

Notice that when we look at the structure of the output, we find that "Rep", "Var1", and so on are actually matrices. So, you can extract them and `cbind` them. But, that's somewhat tedious.

I had to do something similar once a while back, and I ended up just writing a basic wrapper around `aggregate` that looks like this.

```
aggregate2 <- function(data, aggs, ids, funs = NULL, ...) {
  if (identical(aggs, "."))
    aggs <- setdiff(names(data), ids)
  if (identical(ids, "."))
    ids <- setdiff(names(data), aggs)
  if (is.null(funs))
    stop("Aggregation function missing")
  myformula <- as.formula(
    paste(sprintf("cbind(%s)", paste(aggs, collapse = ", ")),
          " ~ ", paste(ids, collapse = " + ")))
  temp <- aggregate(
    formula = eval(myformula), data = data,
    FUN = function(x) sapply(seq_along(funs), 
                             function(z) eval(call(funs[z], quote(x)))), ...)
  temp1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(temp[-c(1:length(ids))], as.data.frame))
  names(temp1) <- paste(rep(aggs, each = length(funs)), funs, sep = ".")
  cbind(temp[1:length(ids)], temp1)
}
```

Here's how you apply it to your example data.

```
(temp2 <- aggregate2(x, ".", c("Temp", "pH"), c("mean", "sd", "length")))
#   Temp  pH Rep.mean Rep.sd Rep.length Var1.mean  Var1.sd Var1.length Var2.mean
# 1   10 7.6        2      1          3  4.281195 1.352194           3  3.534447
# 2   20 7.6        2      1          3  5.840411 1.120549           3  6.907273
# 3   10 8.1        2      1          3  5.583853 2.491672           3  4.116622
# 4   20 8.1        2      1          3  6.635154 2.232262           3  8.893188
#    Var2.sd Var2.length Var3.mean  Var3.sd Var3.length
# 1 1.652884           3 0.1529616 1.076276           3
# 2 8.628021           3 0.1301949 1.764201           3
# 3 1.478286           3 1.1611944 1.081301           3
# 4 4.208087           3 0.5509202 1.187431           3
```

And, the structure is what we expect.

```
str(temp2)
# 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  14 variables:
#  $ Temp       : Factor w/ 2 levels "10","20": 1 2 1 2
#  $ pH         : Factor w/ 2 levels "7.6","8.1": 1 1 2 2
#  $ Rep.mean   : num  2 2 2 2
#  $ Rep.sd     : num  1 1 1 1
#  $ Rep.length : num  3 3 3 3
#  $ Var1.mean  : num  4.28 5.84 5.58 6.64
#  $ Var1.sd    : num  1.35 1.12 2.49 2.23
#  $ Var1.length: num  3 3 3 3
#  $ Var2.mean  : num  3.53 6.91 4.12 8.89
#  $ Var2.sd    : num  1.65 8.63 1.48 4.21
#  $ Var2.length: num  3 3 3 3
#  $ Var3.mean  : num  0.153 0.13 1.161 0.551
#  $ Var3.sd    : num  1.08 1.76 1.08 1.19
#  $ Var3.length: num  3 3 3 3
```

If you don't want to use the function, this is the part that specifically deals with working with the output of `aggregate`, as applied to the "temp" object we created at the start of this answer:

```
temp1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(temp[-c(1:2)], as.data.frame))
funs <- c("mean", "sd", "length")
names(temp1) <- paste(rep(setdiff(names(temp), c("pH", "Temp")), 
                          each = length(funs)), funs, sep = ".")
cbind(temp[1:2], temp1)
```

---

#### Update: A more simple solution

[It turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14759569/1270695) that you can actually just do:

```
do.call(data.frame, 
        aggregate(. ~ Temp + pH, x, function(y) cbind(mean(y), sd(y), length(y))))
```

The downside here is that the names are less descriptive than the `aggregate2` function I shared, but that can be fixed with a pretty straightforward call to `names`.

Comment: Both of these answers give a solution for the problem. Juba's solution takes 3 rows, while yours only one. I think both fulfill the gruesome requirements of "lazy/easy" =). Both of them would deserve to be the accepted answer. I'll let people vote for the best solution and tick that one later.

Comment: @Largh, just an FYI: not sure how big your actual data is. On this example and a few similar ones, sticking to `aggregate2` (which is really just `aggregate` in slight disguise) is about 3 times faster than a "plyr" + `reshape` approach ;)

Comment: @Largh, I [just found](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14759569/1270695) an even better solution: `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ Temp + pH, x, function(y) cbind(mean(y), sd(y), length(y))))`

Comment: To Ananda: could you edit it in you answer, please. I marked your answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @AnandaMahto how would I add in an na.action to your code? both the do.call and also your aggregate2 function. It is so close to what I need but I have Na's in my data

Comment: @Salmosalar, if you're using the `do.call` version, just use `na.action` the same way you would normally use it with `aggregate`. I would recommend that over `aggregate2`.

Comment: Couldnt get it to work completely, however i adapted @juba answer perfectly. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it with `reshape2` and `plyr`. But you get results with variables in rows instead of columns :

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
md <- melt(x[,-1], id.vars=c("Temp","pH"))
ddply(md, c("Temp", "pH", "variable"), summarize, mean=mean(value), sd=sd(value))
```

Which gives :

```
   Temp  pH variable      mean       sd
1    10 7.6     Var1 4.2811952 1.352194
2    10 7.6     Var2 3.5344474 1.652884
3    10 7.6     Var3 0.1529616 1.076276
4    10 8.1     Var1 5.5838533 2.491672
5    10 8.1     Var2 4.1166215 1.478286
6    10 8.1     Var3 1.1611944 1.081301
7    20 7.6     Var1 5.8404110 1.120549
8    20 7.6     Var2 6.9072734 8.628021
9    20 7.6     Var3 0.1301949 1.764201
10   20 8.1     Var1 6.6351538 2.232262
11   20 8.1     Var2 8.8931884 4.208087
12   20 8.1     Var3 0.5509202 1.187431
```

If you want your results in a wide format, you can use `reshape` :

```
md <- melt(x[,-1], id.vars=c("Temp","pH"))
result <- ddply(md, c("Temp", "pH", "variable"), summarize, mean=mean(value), sd=sd(value))
reshape(result, idvar=c("Temp","pH"), timevar="variable",direction="wide")

   Temp  pH mean.Var1  sd.Var1 mean.Var2  sd.Var2 mean.Var3  sd.Var3
1    10 7.6  4.281195 1.352194  3.534447 1.652884 0.1529616 1.076276
4    10 8.1  5.583853 2.491672  4.116622 1.478286 1.1611944 1.081301
7    20 7.6  5.840411 1.120549  6.907273 8.628021 0.1301949 1.764201
10   20 8.1  6.635154 2.232262  8.893188 4.208087 0.5509202 1.187431
```

Comment: Nice shortcut =) I didn't think of that although I played with reshape2. Thanks!

Comment: I just edited my answer to add a way to get your result in a "wide" format.

Comment: Nice work here. I haven't used `plyr` much, so it's good to see some worked out examples.