# How can I use functions returning vectors (like fivenum) with ddply or aggregate?

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I would like to split my data frame using a couple of columns and call let's say `fivenum` on each group.

```
aggregate(Petal.Width ~ Species, iris, function(x) summary(fivenum(x)))
```

The returned value is a data.frame with only 2 columns and the second being a matrix. How can I turn it into normal columns of a data.frame?

**Update**

I want something like the following with less code using `fivenum`

```
ddply(iris, .(Species), summarise,
      Min = min(Petal.Width),
      Q1 = quantile(Petal.Width, .25),
      Med = median(Petal.Width),
      Q3 = quantile(Petal.Width, .75),
      Max = max(Petal.Width)
      )
```

Comment: The returned value is a `data.frame` of seven columns. It has nothing to do with a `matrix`. Maybe if you showed the results you were expecting, it would be easier to answer this question.

Comment: @nograpes Try wrapping the sample line into `length()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `do.call` to call `data.frame` on each of the matrix elements recursively to get a data.frame with vector elements:

```
dim(do.call("data.frame",dfr))
[1] 3 7

str(do.call("data.frame",dfr))
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Species            : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 2 3
 $ Petal.Width.Min.   : num  0.1 1 1.4
 $ Petal.Width.1st.Qu.: num  0.2 1.2 1.8
 $ Petal.Width.Median : num  0.2 1.3 2
 $ Petal.Width.Mean   : num  0.28 1.36 2
 $ Petal.Width.3rd.Qu.: num  0.3 1.5 2.3
 $ Petal.Width.Max.   : num  0.6 1.8 2.5
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution using `data.table` (while not specifically requested, it is an obvious compliment or replacement for `aggregate` or `ddply`. As well as being slightly long to code, repeatedly calling `quantile` will be inefficient, as for each call you will be sorting the data

```
library(data.table)
Tukeys_five <- c("Min","Q1","Med","Q3","Max") 

IRIS <- data.table(iris)
# this will create the wide data.table
lengthBySpecies <- IRIS[,as.list(fivenum(Sepal.Length)), by = Species]

# and you can rename the columns from V1, ..., V5 to something nicer

setnames(lengthBySpecies, paste0('V',1:5), Tukeys_five)


lengthBySpecies



      Species Min  Q1 Med  Q3 Max
1:     setosa 4.3 4.8 5.0 5.2 5.8
2: versicolor 4.9 5.6 5.9 6.3 7.0
3:  virginica 4.9 6.2 6.5 6.9 7.9
```

Or, using a single call to `quantile` using the appropriate `prob` argument.

```
IRIS[,as.list(quantile(Sepal.Length, prob = seq(0,1, by = 0.25))), by = Species]


       Species  0%   25% 50% 75% 100%
1:     setosa 4.3 4.800 5.0 5.2  5.8
2: versicolor 4.9 5.600 5.9 6.3  7.0
3:  virginica 4.9 6.225 6.5 6.9  7.9
```

Note that the names of the created columns are not syntactically valid, although you could go through a similar renaming using `setnames`

---

EDIT

Interestingly, `quantile` will set the names of the resulting vector if you set `names = TRUE`, and this will copy (slow down the number crunching and consume memory - it even warns you in the help, fancy that!)

Thus, you should probably use

```
 IRIS[,as.list(quantile(Sepal.Length, prob = seq(0,1, by = 0.25), names = FALSE)), by = Species]
```

Or, if you wanted to return the named list, without `R` copying internally

```
IRIS[,{quant <- as.list(quantile(Sepal.Length, prob = seq(0,1, by = 0.25), names = FALSE))
       setattr(quant, 'names', Tukeys_five)
       quant}, by = Species]
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there isn't an exact way to do what you're asking, because the function you're using (fivenum) doesn't return data in a way that can be easily bound to columns from within the 'ddply' function.  This is easy to clean up, though, in a programmatic way.

**Step 1**: Perform the `fivenum` function on each 'Species' value using the 'ddply' function.

```
data <- ddply(iris, .(Species), summarize, value=fivenum(Petal.Width))

#       Species value
# 1      setosa   0.1
# 2      setosa   0.2
# 3      setosa   0.2
# 4      setosa   0.3
# 5      setosa   0.6
# 6  versicolor   1.0
# 7  versicolor   1.2
# 8  versicolor   1.3
# 9  versicolor   1.5
# 10 versicolor   1.8
# 11  virginica   1.4
# 12  virginica   1.8
# 13  virginica   2.0
# 14  virginica   2.3
# 15  virginica   2.5
```

Now, the 'fivenum' function returns a list, so we end up with 5 line entries for each species.  That's the part where the 'fivenum' function is fighting us.

**Step 2**: Add a label column.  We know what Tukey's five numbers are, so we just call them out in the order that the 'fivenum' function returns them.  The list will repeat until it hits the end of the data.

```
Tukeys_five <- c("Min","Q1","Med","Q3","Max") 
data$label <- Tukeys_five

#       Species value label
# 1      setosa   0.1   Min
# 2      setosa   0.2    Q1
# 3      setosa   0.2   Med
# 4      setosa   0.3    Q3
# 5      setosa   0.6   Max
# 6  versicolor   1.0   Min
# 7  versicolor   1.2    Q1
# 8  versicolor   1.3   Med
# 9  versicolor   1.5    Q3
# 10 versicolor   1.8   Max
# 11  virginica   1.4   Min
# 12  virginica   1.8    Q1
# 13  virginica   2.0   Med
# 14  virginica   2.3    Q3
# 15  virginica   2.5   Max
```

**Step 3**: With the labels in place, we can quickly cast this data into a new shape using the 'dcast' function from the 'reshape2' package.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(data, Species ~ label)[,c("Species",Tukeys_five)]

#      Species Min  Q1 Med  Q3 Max
# 1     setosa 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.6
# 2 versicolor 1.0 1.2 1.3 1.5 1.8
# 3  virginica 1.4 1.8 2.0 2.3 2.5
```

All that junk at the end are just specifying the column order, since the 'dcast' function automatically puts things in alphabetical order.

Hope this helps.

**Update**: I decided to return, because I realized there is one other option available to you.  You can always bind a matrix as part of a data frame definition, so you could resolve your 'aggregate' function like so:

```
data <- aggregate(Petal.Width ~ Species, iris, function(x) summary(fivenum(x))) 
result <- data.frame(Species=data[,1],data[,2])

#      Species Min. X1st.Qu. Median Mean X3rd.Qu. Max.
# 1     setosa  0.1      0.2    0.2 0.28      0.3  0.6
# 2 versicolor  1.0      1.2    1.3 1.36      1.5  1.8
# 3  virginica  1.4      1.8    2.0 2.00      2.3  2.5
```

Comment: I was thinking about casting data. I usually use *reshape* for that but it is nice to see how it can be done with plyr. Your updated answer is essentially what James suggested. I forgot that one can "cbind" data.frames including implicit conversion from matrix like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
ddply(iris, .(Species), summarize, value=t(fivenum(Petal.Width)))
```

Comment: And how is it different from what *Dinre* wrote?

Comment: It is simple, short and slick. Here, the vector values of "fivenum" form a matrix. So the result has two columns, one is the labels and the other one is a matrix of five columns

Comment: You will be surprised by calling *ncol* on that.

Comment: I just applied _ncol_ , and the result was 2, as I mentioned above

Comment: Oops, my bad, I missed you acknowledge that earlier. Anyway discussion goes to nowhere and solution is no different than **Step 1** from *Dinre*. It is somewhat unusable as there are too many levels of indirection and in most cases it needs to be flattened.

Comment: To see the differences with **Step 1**, you only need to try them: copy and paste them in your R console and run them. I use this format frequently. For example, if A is the output of my code above, then kmeans(A[,2], 2) clusters the population based on their finvenum. I don't know why you feel there are "too many levels of indirections" I am sure every analyst can handle the t() operator acting on a vector. At the end, I agree with you that this discussion goes to nowhere